# Is there a way in SQL Server to solve for this conditional problem for prioritization?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following schema of a table

```
Name     Number
-----    -------
A           200
A           322
B           200
B           322
C           322
C           200
D           322
D           234
```

I need some conditional statement to add another label column.

1. The conditions being that if a name has number 200, it should be prioritized over all other numbers and be labeled as 'Apple'
2. The next condition is that if a name does not have a number 200, the second priority is for number 322. So then those should be labeled as 'Mango'

I want my final result to look something like this which is grouped by name.

```
Name     Number     Label
-----    -------    ------
A          200       Apple
B          200       Apple
C          200       Apple
D          322       Mango
```

Comment: Order by a `CASE` that assigns priority based on number. e.g., `ORDER BY CASE Number WHEN 200 THEN 0 WHEN 322 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END`. You would do something similar in the `SELECT` to assign the labels. Or if this is something you're trying to maintain, add another table that associates number, fruit, and priority.

Comment: Your desired output leaves a bit of confusion. Is the output grouped by `Name` or have you just shared a simplified subset that happens to be four unique `Name` values? Given that your question makes no mention of the `Name` column, combined with your output described as "something *like* this", it's all a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @TylerRoper Yes, It is grouped by the Name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select
  name,
  case min(case number when 200 then 0 when 322 then 1 end) 
    when 0 then 'Apple'
    when 1 then 'Mango'
  end Label 
from tablename
group by name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ad359f9e2fb5878326cb36c31932cca0).
Results:

```
> name | Label
> :--- | :----
> A    | Apple
> B    | Apple
> C    | Apple
> D    | Mango
```

If you want the column `Number` also do the aggregation inside a CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select name, min(case number when 200 then 0 when 322 then 1 end) id
  from tablename
  group by name
)
select 
  name,
  case id when 0 then 200 when 1 then 322 end Number,
  case id when 0 then 'Apple' when 1 then 'Mango' end Label
from cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2cc1a0bdbcdd81032d3b8e9bb02de6e7).
Results:

```
> name | Number | Label
> :--- | -----: | :----
> A    |    200 | Apple
> B    |    200 | Apple
> C    |    200 | Apple
> D    |    322 | Mango
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN [Number]=200 THEN 'APPLE' WHEN [Number] =322 THEN 'MANGO' ELSE 'WHATEVER' END) [Label], [Number]
FROM [Yourtablename]
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN [Number]=200 THEN 2 WHEN [Number] =322 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
```

Comment: You and I seemed to have a similar understanding of the question, however I believe we've both misunderstood. It seems that OP only wants to select one item per unique `Name` based on the priority, as opposed to simply ordering the results.

Comment: Yeah I agree... Or his output is over-simplified? 

Comment: Not sure, that's what I thought myself. I've commented for clarification.

Comment: Yes. The OP only wants to select one item per unique name. That's correct